# Using Redux without React to export functions

Tags: javascript, redux

I want to be able to create a list of functions that are connected to Redux without using any React so that I can use these functions in various components across my app. How can I do this without using React / react components? Please see the below for my approach. Am I able to use react-redux's `connect`? Thanks.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchUsers} from './actions';

class Sample {
  getUsers() {
    this.props.fetchUsers();
  }

  displayUser() {
    if (this.props.isSignedIn) {
      return (
        <h1>`The user ID is: ${this.props.userId}`</h1>
      );
    }
  }
}

Sample.propTypes = {
  isSignedIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  userId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  fetchUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isSignedIn: state.isSignedIn,
  userId: state.userId,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchUsers: () => {
    dispatch(fetchUsers());
  },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Sample);
```

You can also see here for my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {ConnectedRouter} from 'react-router-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import App from './app';

const history = createHistory();
const store = configureStore(history);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

Comment: Is this React or not React? I'm confused with what you're doing here. `react-redux` is for react.

Comment: Ok thanks, this would not be react, just vanilla js that needs to be connected to redux. So then how do I connect my redux store without using `connect` for vanilla js?

Comment: You use `store.subscribe()`

https://redux.js.org/basics/store

You could implement your own connect function using it.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my most recent edit. How would I get my store into a specific file so I can then subscribe to it?

Comment: Move your store to a configureStore file, create the store in there and export it. Then import it where you need it.